# Only execute maven-release-plugin deploy steps for a specific sub-module/project

Tags: maven, nexus, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin, sonatype

I have a maven project that is organized as:

MyProject

- Core (parent -> oss.sonatype.org)
- Package (parent -> MyProject)

MyProject and Package are used in bundling the project up for a proprietary deployment method (creates a specialized Zip)

**What I want to do is be able to deploy the Core project to the OSS Sonatype Nexus Repo for used via Maven Dependencies in other projects.**

"MyProject" is checked into github along with its sub-projects (Core, Package).

My problem is when I do a maven release:perform (in the Core dir), it checks out MyProject from github, and then runs maven deploy against the Parent's pom -- since it is the pom in the root of the checkout.

I dont want to deal with nested git repos; figuring out how to maintain MyProject and Package in one repo, and Core in another.

So, how can I either:

1. Tell maven-release-plugin (included via the oss.sonatype.org parent pom) to execute only against the Core project.
2. Tell maven-release-plugin to skip all deploy actions on the MyProject and Package projects. (I think i would prefer this since, if it maven-release-plugin could keep my POM versions in sync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can't release a module if you don't release the parent.

I checked the documentation about plugin and you can release a parent but I don't found information about release a child only.

See: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/faq.html#nonrecursive